# Do you lose your +2 edit rep if the edited post is subsequently deleted?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Do you lose the +2 edit rep if the edited post is subsequently deleted?

It seems a little unfair if this is true, but reputation can evaporate in this way in similar circumstances.

Comment: I would imagine so, but have no evidence to back this up.

Comment: confirmed, both @Michaels have the right answer :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

TL;DR: After testing with [this other answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78148/152859), I can confirm the reputation gained for suggesting an edit is gone when the post is deleted.

---

Here are the full steps taken:

1. I edited Benny's (now-deleted) answer, and I immediately got 2 points for the edit, after it was approved.
2. Benny deleted his answer, and although I retained the points in my total rep, they were dropped from my [reputation report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/reputation).
3. I did a recalc, and as expected, the 2 points I got for editing Benny's answer disappeared.

In that respect, the behavior is exactly the same as that seen when you get points for a post, then delete that post. The points stick around until your reputation is recalculated.

---

**Editor's note:** In the past, there used to be a "Recalculate" button in the [Reputation Report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/reputation) page, however it was removed after improving the automated reputation synchronization process.

Comment: I did it and now it is deleted do a recalc and see what happens

Comment: @Benny: I just did a recalc, and as predicted, the points disappeared.

Answer (score 10):

It's probably worth noting you won't lose your reputation from the suggested edits if the post is 60 or more days old and has a score of 3 or higher. This is similar to authors not losing reputation for upvotes on such a post after it is deleted, as documented in e.g. the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/295232) and [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/). (Source: I just scienced it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/276748/timeline#history_34909297-b684-46c9-8df1-2e8ed66b1d1a) - I did trigger a reputation recalculation to be sure.)

Answer (score 6):

I would expect it to be just like rep from upvotes on that post -- you lose it if your rep is recalculated