# Regaining edit rep

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

There is a question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78147/do-you-lose-your-2-edit-rep-if-the-edited-question-is-subsequently-deleted) about whether you lose rep gained from an edit if the question is deleted.  The consensus seems to be that you *would* lose the 2 rep.

Let's say I edit 500 questions, hitting the rep cap of 1000 for editing.  If one question is deleted and I lose the rep, and I edit another question, can I still get 2 rep?  Or would I not get it because I had hit the 1000 cap?

Comment: Wow, running this site involves rewriting time and history a lot, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

I would think if an edited post is deleted and then you edit another one, you'd get rep immediately, and if you had 501 edits then a recalc after a deletion wouldn't change your rep -- you'd lose 2 from the deleted post, and gain 2 from the 501st edit. It's probably not just a flag that says "this person never gets rep from editing again"