# Edits/votes on deleted questions - do they disappear?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I'm aware that when a question is deleted or migrated that any rep gained from the question or an answer disappears.  But if you've voted on the question/answers, or made an edit, do those still count towards, say, a badge?  Or do they disappear as well?

Rep gained from edits [seems to disappear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78147/do-you-lose-your-2-edit-rep-if-the-edited-post-is-subsequently-deleted), which makes sense, so I suspect all record of the votes/edits disappears.  But it would be nice to know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, reps on deleted posts will disappear upon recalc, you can check post id on deleted post are gone at [/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) page, but migrated questions are just closed on original site, so it will stay until the post get deleted.

And badge will not disappear automatically, but you won't get next badge for same pattern.

Not sure about edits, but they probably not counting on deleted posts too.