# Losing 2 reputation earned by editing questions before 2k rep

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you lose your +2 edit rep if the edited post is subsequently deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78147/do-you-lose-your-2-edit-rep-if-the-edited-post-is-subsequently-deleted)

There was a time when I lost 2 reputation on SO (when I had around 2200 rep) but I didn't find any downvotes that could have caused it.

So I was wondering *is it possible to lose 2 reputation earned by editing questions/answers before I got 2k reputation, when someone edits that question/answer again after I had more then 2k reputation*?

I know that there are other explanations like "author just removed that edited post" or "it must be downvote, check again" but I am really interested in situation mentioned before.

Comment: @downvoter could you explain why -1?

Comment: See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for comment. I assume that downvote is kind of "no" answer :)

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78147/do-you-lose-your-2-edit-rep-if-the-edited-post-is-subsequently-deleted

Comment: @martinclayton Thank you for link, although I was more interested in after-edit than deleting post.

Comment: I don't think you lose rep if there is a subsequent edit.

Comment: @martinclayton I think you are right but I wont be 100% sure unless I see some edit that gave someone +2 and was edited again by someone else after that person had more than 2k reputation.

Comment: OK - find one you have +2 rep from, and I'll edit it for you.  How about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11590709/revisions

Comment: @martinclayton If that is not problem then maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11169909/revisions) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10766674/revisions) would be better (I am sure I got +2 for them)

Comment: I've edited both those posts.  Your rep should have updated if it was going to, but to confirm, you can always recalc: http://stackoverflow.com/reputation?recalc=true

Comment: @martinclayton So my theory in question is false. I am so glad :D. Thank you for your help. Sorry for my late answer but I wasn't able to use Internet till now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you check the 'show removed posts' checkbox on your reputation page? It could be a post you edited was deleted. Not sure if that then means you lost the 2 rep for the suggested edit.

Whatever happened, it should be visible in your reputation history with the 'show removed posts' option checked.

Comment: Thank for solving that mystery. I thought that checking that option will only show me posts removed by me, didn't expect post removed by others.

Comment: @MartjinPieters: Shouldn't you gain back reputation for down voted post being deleted?

Comment: @nhahtdh: entirely correct; removed that from the answer as I was incorrect there.

Comment: although it appears to not be the case here, unaccepting an answer to a question you asked would also result in the loss of 2 rep.