# Do you lose rep if your edit is rolled back?

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits

The situation:  A < 2k rep user suggests and edit, which is then approved.  They gain +2 rep for this action.  Later the edit is rolled back.  Does the +2 rep disappear?

Related but not an answer to this question: [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78147/do-you-lose-your-2-edit-rep-if-the-edited-post-is-subsequently-deleted).

Comment: Moderator BoltClock seems to think no: [Reject an already-approved suggested edit when rolling it back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137755)

Comment: @Dennis Hmm, interesting!  And that's a rather recent post, too.  I ask because I've been doing a lot of editing today, and at times my rep is magically decreasing by 2 when I refresh, even though I don't see any negative rep explanations in the reputation section of my profile.  Maybe BoltClock's suggestion was implemented? /curious

Comment: And deleted posts wouldn't explain the drops? You can check for those if you tick **show removed posts** on your reputation overview.

Comment: @Dennis Wasn't aware of that box, thanks for the info!  It didn't change anything on my rep page, though.

Comment: I don't believe reputation retractions from deleted suggested edits show up in the reputation history. Feature request?

Comment: @animuson If you do in fact lose rep for this, then yes, definitely a feature request!  Since nothing does show up, I wasn't sure if you lost rep for them or not.  It seems like you do, based on my experience, but I haven't found any hard evidence to back it up.

Comment: @animuson: I think they do: [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AlCZ3.png) -- the only interaction I had with that question was a [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566167/upload-a-picture-friends-list-for-an-event-using-the-facebook-graph-api).

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Good to know. I've never had a suggested edit on a deleted post before, I've only heard that people can't find the events.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer your primary question: **no**, a rollback does not cause a reversal of the reputation gained (although some people wish it did). The only thing that will cause you to lose reputation from a suggested edit is if the post gets deleted*.

* However, this isn't true for orphaned tag wikis since they never actually get deleted; they just float off into imagination land.

Comment: `they just float off into imagination land.` Actually they are kept around, in a mod only list of "orphaned wikis", a list no mod ever has found any use for...

Comment: Shhhh, let them imagine things.