# Do you actually lose rep if your edit was rolled back by the author?

Tags: support, bug, reputation, edits, rollbacks

I've found this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142492/260198), where an SE employee stated that:

> a rollback does not cause a reversal of the reputation gained

But check [this question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1058182/revisions).

> [image]

1. Edit was approved.
2. Member got reputation.
3. Author rolled back edit.
4. Member lost reputation.

Was something changed in the logic?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A *normal* rollback won't cause you to lose the 2 reputation.

But when the post author [overrides the edit approval](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/295232), this causes a rollback *and* the 2 reputation will be lost, since the suggested edit isn't 'approved' anymore and that is what gives you the 2 reputation.

This is reflected in the [suggested edit](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/424048); the oldest reviews say 'Принять' ('Approve'), so the edit was initially approved, but then the post author decided to 'Отклонить' ('Reject') the edit.

[image]

Comment: So, [tag:status-bad-design]?

Comment: It was probably easiest this way, but not necessarily bad.