# Removed post gives me -2 reputation. What happened?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I deleted an answer which had no upvotes or downvotes, but after some time I saw that my reputation was -2 and the reason is linked to my search engine.

[image]

I want to know why this happened and what "linked to my serach engine" means?

Comment: `"linked to my search engine"` is simply the title of that post...

Comment: I don't really understand the problem...you lost reputation because it was deleted, but *you* deleted it? Try to make the issue here a little clearer. :)

Comment: No, it was not your question and you did not delete it. "linked to my serach engine" is the title of the question that got removed.

Comment: I answered one question after sometime i deleted that answer, so i get -2 and linked to my search engine in reason.

Comment: Close voters: Despite the business about "linked to my serach engine", this is actually a potentially useful post for any sub-10k user who sees -2 from a removed post, since they have no way to see it and it's unlikely they'll figure out that they suggested an edit on it otherwise.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is unrelated to the answer you deleted.

You [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/306466) to [a question titled "linked to my serach engine"[sic]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321763/linked-to-my-serach-engine) <sub><sup>(10k-only link)</sup></sub>, and the suggestion was accepted, gaining you two rep points.

The question was later closed, then deleted by three other users (Charles, Mat, and John Saunders). The two rep from your edit [was removed along with the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78147/do-you-lose-your-2-edit-rep-if-the-edited-post-is-subsequently-deleted).