# Lost reputation from a deleted post that I'm not it's owner

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removed post gives me -2 reputation. What happened?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145242/removed-post-gives-me-2-reputation-what-happened)

Weird thing, I just noticed I lost reputation (*-2*) from [a deleted post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817385/silverlight-app-using-mvc-or-rest-web-services) which I'm not it's owner, nor participate in.

Another weird thing, the question has no votes and no answers were provided, how is it possible?

My reputation changes:

[image]

The deleted question:

[image]

<sub>It's important to me to indicate, I'm not whining on the horrible rep lost, I think I'll get over this, but it seems like something is broken...</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You had [submitted a suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8817385/revisions) on that post to remove a signature on January 11th, 2012, and the +2 reputation you got at the time from it being accepted disappeared when the post was removed.

Comment: Nice catch, it was reedited since than so I didn't notice, and I almost forgot that you can get reputation from editing stuff with low reputation.