# Why does my reputation go down when someone else's answer gets deleted?

Tags: support, reputation, edits, deleted-questions

I was looking at my recent reputation changes today, and it said that I received -2 reputation because "Python program keeps hanging, no error message, just stalls at the same point" got deleted. The problem here was that this wasn't even my question, it's just that I had edited it earlier. Can someone help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: You got +2 for editing it. Once it's deleted it's as if it never existed and the +2 is lost

Comment: More specific duplicate is [Removed post gives me 2 reputation -- what happened?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145242)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2 rep you earned when you edited the question was reversed when the answer was deleted.  This is a normal feature - when a contribution is deleted, all rep gained from it is also removed.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! now I get it.. I thought this was a bug :)