# Two reputation subtracted for question that doesn't belong to me

Tags: support, reputation

My account had 2 reputation deducted for a question which I haven't asked. The question also doesn't appear in my question asked list. Why did it happen? Will I be refunded my reputation points?

Here is the link for the reputation page:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/2776146/kptryin?tab=reputation

The change in reputation was on december 28th.

[image: Edited One]

Comment: You should at least post a pic or link to it. We have no clue as to where & when of the problem.

Comment: We can't see the item you're referring to. Please post an image of your reputation page, and a link to the question.

Comment: Post the title of the question for which you got -2, we can't see it in your reputation tab.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta no link for <10K users, but title will be enough to search and hopefully Google cached it. :)

Comment: Please click either "post" or "time" next to "graph" and then take screenshot. Graph does not provide details.

Comment: Have you Downvoted any answers?

Comment: No, I haven't down-voted

Comment: OK, here is [link to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659492/write-a-small-program-using-jquery-and-javascript-that-can-take-a-number-and-pri). (10K only)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On December 18, you [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3612111) an edit to a [question titled "javaWrite a small program using JQuery and JavaScript that can take a number and print it upside down on the screen"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659492/write-a-small-program-using-jquery-and-javascript-that-can-take-a-number-and-pri).

[image]

That suggestion was accepted, and you received two points. Unfortunately, that question was poorly received, heavily downvoted, closed, and finally deleted on December 28. When it was deleted, you [lost the points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78147/do-you-lose-your-2-edit-rep-if-the-edited-post-is-subsequently-deleted) you gained from your suggestion.

Deleted posts are hidden in many places - that's why we can't see it in your reputation history, and why you won't be able to visit the links above, until you have at least 10k reputation.

Answer (score 7):

Probably you got two points for editing that question, but if that question is removed, the points that you gained for the editing are also removed.

Comment: In my reputation graph, I don't have the +2 reputation change shown

Comment: @KPTryin: I don't see any other reason than the editing points that are removed.

Comment: Why doesn't it show the +2 reputation change when I might have edited it?

Comment: @KPTryin: I'm not sure, but probably it didn't include the +2 because this +2 was removed.

Comment: Is it a bug or purposeful?

Comment: @KPTryin: I think it is by design, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @KPTryin it's not a bug.

Comment: Correct, [here is the suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3612111) - please embed into your answer. :)